# I can't re-render app.js on login/logout from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't find a solution on how to re-render app.js function.
It's loaded first time, but when I click login or logout button I need to call a function from the helper again to check user status.
App.js

```
import Routes from "./Routes";

import NavBar from "./common/navBar";
import { isAuthenticated } from "./helpers/checkAuthentication";


function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    {
      console.log("useEffect", isAuthenticated());
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      {console.log("INININ", isAuthenticated())}
      <div
        className={
          isAuthenticated()
            ? "loggedIn internalDashboard"
            : "loggedOut internalDashboard"
        }>
        {isAuthenticated() ? (
          <div className='menu'>
            <NavBar />
          </div>
        ) : null}

        <div className='mainContent'>
          <Routes />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.jsx

```
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [, forceRender] = useReducer((s) => s + 1, 0);
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
    const userInfo = {
      email: values.email
    };
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    history.push("/");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    console.log("IN");
    if (user) {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      history.push("/");
    }
  });

  return (
    <Form
      name='basic'
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}>
      <Form.Item
        label='Username'
        name='email'
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your email!" }]}>
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label='Password'
        name='password'
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your password!" }]}>
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

In console.log:
INININ true
navBar.jsx:66 dsadsadsddasadsa true
App.js:11 useEffect true

This part will be loaded only first time on pageload, after that I need to reload page to see new status

On lick login button localstorage will receive new data, but app.js will not check authentication and show `<NavBar />`. And if I click logout user will be removed from localstorage but I can see `<NavBar />`, and I need to refresh page and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `Context API` to save and update your global state without connecting any state management library such as `redux`, `mobx` and so on. Thanks to this API you will be able always to know whether a user is authenticated or not.

So, I have found a very interesting article that must help you to resolve your issue. Let's me attach the link: https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/